# How could I set my display rotation via Terminal?

Tags: terminal, rotation, applescript, settings, display

I have a dual monitor setup and I'd love to write a simple AppleScript app that when I double-click it, will toggle the rotation between 0 and 90º.

Google has so far failed me, and the one thing I did find, `displaytracer` installed via `brew`, doesn't successfully install on Big Sur and fails to find a needed Xcode Command Line Tools (mine are all installed).

Comment: RE: "displaytracer" -- Is that the correct package name? Have your heard of or tried [displayplacer](https://github.com/jakehilborn/displayplacer)? You can download it directly from its GitHub page and the **displayplacer-master.zip** _file_ already contain a _compiled executable_, or you can delete it and compile from _source_ with just the `make` _command_, if you have  **Xcode Command Line Tools** installed.

Comment: FYI While this can be done in **AppleScript**, nonetheless, you do not want to do that if you can download and manually install `displayplacer` from its GitHub page. To do it with basic vanilla **AppleScript** it involves **UI Scripting** and it is kludgy and prone to failure unless coded with appropriate _error handling_.  I'd use `displayplacer` even it you wanted to wrap it in **AppleScript**.